# How to return a value or an object in Eiffel?

Tags: syntax, eiffel

Is the **Result** keyword automatically recognized as the return value/object?
What is the proper syntax to be used?
Unfortunately, I cannot find a clear indication from the documentation and the various examples online.

Comment: What or where is "the documentation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword **Result** is just a local variable with a reserved name and the ability to use it in a feature body as well as in the corresponding postcondition. The last value attached to **Result** before exiting the feature is the value returned by this feature. Here is an example:

```
foo: SOMETHING
    do
        Result := bar
        if Result.whatever then
            qux (Result)
        else
            something_else := Result
            Result := some_other_value
        end
    ensure
        valid_result: Result.is_valid
    end
```

There is a validity rule that states that **Result** can be used only in features that return a value, because it has no meaning in procedures that do not return anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alexander!Can the Result also return an object?

Comment: @vkouk, what do you mean by "return an object"? The expressions `bar` and `some_other_value` are evaluated at run-time and produce some object that is attached to `Result`. This object is then returned by the function `foo`. All values in Eiffel are objects.

Comment: I thought there were also native types as in other high-level languages, now I understand. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @vkouk, indeed, there are types the compiler knows about in advance. They are required to handle literal values such as `True` or `5`. Other than that all types follow the same set of rules. So, `True` denotes an instance of an expanded class `BOOLEAN`, `5` denotes an instance of an expanded class `INTEGER`, `"ABC"` denotes an instance of a reference class `STRING`, etc. All these instances are objects.